# Contact PXSelector not showing DisplayName Properly

Tags: acumatica

I am using a PXSelector to choose a contact record. The PXSelector and PXRestrictor works, and I see only active contacts for a particular customer record. However, on the screen it is showing the contact id, hyphen and display name (for example "12345 - Smith, John"). I want it to just show the display name without the id. Here is the code I am using in the DAC:

```
[PXDBInt()]
[PXUIField(DisplayName = "Billing Contact", Visibility = PXUIVisibility.Visible)]
[PXSelector(typeof(Search2<Contact.contactID,
        LeftJoin<BAccount, On<BAccount.bAccountID, Equal<Contact.bAccountID>>>>),
    DescriptionField = typeof(Contact.displayName),
    Filterable = true,
    DirtyRead = true)]
[PXRestrictor(typeof(Where<Contact.contactType, NotEqual<ContactTypesAttribute.bAccountProperty>,
            And<WhereEqualNotNull<BAccount.bAccountID, Customer.bAccountID>>>), PX.Objects.CR.Messages.ContactBAccountDiff, typeof(Contact.displayName))]
[PXRestrictor(typeof(Where<Contact.isActive, Equal<True>>), PX.Objects.CR.Messages.ContactInactive, typeof(Contact.displayName))]

public virtual int? UsrBillingContactId { get; set; }
public abstract class usrBillingContactId : IBqlField { }
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Have you added DisplayMode="Text" to your px:PXSelector in the ASPX markup of the page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the TextField selector property to the Description field.
This value could be 'Contact__DisplayName' for your example

You can use the customization project editor to locate the Description field from the selector joined table:
[image]

To set the TextField property you need to show all properties using the funnel button:
[image]

Comment: Thank you! I thought there was a way to do it through the DAC rather than customizing it on the screen, but this looks great.

Comment: To my knowledge is only possible in ASPX.